# Who discovered that electromagnetic wave doesn't need a medium?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, history, aether

I have read that physicists in 19 century searching for the aether. They thought that light must have some medium to carry.

When did they know that light and other electromagnetic wave doesn't need a medium?

Answer (score 7):

> When did they know that light and other electromagnetic wave doesn't need a medium?

Physicists had an inkling early in the 20th century with the development of Planck's law in 1900, Einstein's development of special relativity in 1905, and Einstein's explanation of the photoelectric effect, also in 1905. This strongly suggested that electromagnetism was carried by a particle, the photon.

Stronger evidence came in the 1920s with a number of experiments and a better form of quantum mechanics. (The old quantum theory such as the Bohr model was fundamentally flawed.) Even stronger evidence came in the 1940s and 1950s with the development of quantum electrodynamics.

What about the Michelson-Morley experiment? Contrary to popular current portrayal, that experiment was not perceived at the time as evidence that the luminiferous aether did not exist. It instead was perceived as showing that the luminiferous aether, if it did exist, did not work the way physicists of the latter half of the 19th century initially thought it would work.

A good number of physicists during the final decades of the 19th century worked on reconciling the conflict between Newtonian mechanics and Maxwell's electrodynamics. Most of them postulated a rather weird aether. It wasn't until 1905 that Einstein showed that the aether wasn't needed, and even then, that did not quite explain what electromagnetism was.

Comment: I really don't understand what this answer is hinting at. It must have been known a long time that light easily traverses high vacuum (so we can see celestial bodies) so it seems the only reason to hypothesise aether in the first place was conceptual (not experimental): the need of a reference frame for the finite speed of light in the classical space-time conception (speed must be measured relative to something). Removing that need was the main motivation and achievement of Special Relativity. While it may not explain electromagnetism entirely, SR makes the notion of aether quite pointless.

Comment: thankyou very much. I still have a question. How do electromagnetic waves propagate on their own? by particle or the way they move is not use a medium?

Comment: @Ja-oJack - There are some phenomena such as the photoelectric effect and Compton scattering where light does not look like a wave. Early quantum physicists focused on explaining these non-wavelike features of light. Explaining how light could indeed appear as wavelike even though it is quantized took a great deal more effort. Physicists didn't have a good picture of that until the 1950s. Developing that theory is what won Richard Feynman and others their Nobel prize.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - Re *It must have been known a long time that light easily traverses high vacuum ...* That's obvious now, but it was anything but obvious in the late 19th century. The top physicists of the day tried to determine the properties of the aether that carried light. In their minds, an aether *had* to exist because wave phenomena need a medium.

Comment: Many older physicists held fast to the idea of a luminiferous aether well past Einstein's *Annus Mirabilis*. Case in point: [Sagnac, Georges. "On the proof of the reality of the luminiferous aether by the experiment with a rotating interferometer." *Comptes Rendus* 157 (1913): 1410-1413](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Proof_of_the_Reality_of_the_Luminiferous_Aether).

Answer (score 3):

The [Michelson-Morley experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) was the first good evidence they had that there is no luminiferous aether, and was conducted in 1887. (Michelson had an experiment in 1881 trying to do the same, but it was flawed)

Comment: the experiment show that there is no medium, but I mean when they know that electromagnetic wave can move by themselves and how.

Comment: @Ja-oJack: Fact 1 (known before): There are EM waves. Fact 2: (found by MM experiment): There is no medium carrying EM waves. Conclusion: EM waves have no medium, and so must propagate on their own. What is your question?

Comment: how do they propagate on their own? I don't know the physicists at that time had already known how they propagate on their own. sorry for my question.

Comment: @Ja-oJack: *How do they propagate?* - Well, the changing electric field induces a changing magnetic field induces a changing electric field induces a changing magnetic field...and so on, and so forth.

Comment: ok. The physicists knew how they propagate but didn't know that they can propagate on their own until michaelson-morley experiment show that there is no medium. I get it, thankyou very much.

Comment: That the MM experiment disproved the luminiferous aether is a modern portrayal. That is not how that negative result was viewed at the time. Every wave phenomenon known to mankind at that time needed a medium. How could electromagnetism be any different? The general perception of the MM experiment was that whatever medium carried electromagnetic waves had to be very weird.